# ui-router state does not refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a hard time understanding why when I'm in a press the refresh button while in any state it will always reload the games state. The only difference between the states is that the games state is loaded with state.go('games') after a successful login. What would I have to add/change in order for the states to reload when the refresh button is pressed.

```
game.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('signUp', {
   url: '/signUp',
   templateUrl: 'templates/signUp.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('login', {
   url: '/login',
   templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('games', {
   url: '/games',
   templateUrl: 'templates/games.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
   url: '/dashboard',
   templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
   controller: 'dashboard.controller'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('createGame', {
   url: '/createGame',
   templateUrl: 'templates/createGame.html'
  });

  // $stateProvider.state('viewGame', {
  //  url: '/viewGame',
  //  templateUrl: 'templates/viewGame.html',
  //  controller: 'viewGame.controller'
  // });
}]);

games.controller('games.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', '$firebaseArray','Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, $firebaseArray, fire) {

  $scope.games = $firebaseArray(fire.child('games'));
  // $scope.players = $firebaseArray(fire.child('players'));
  $scope.view = 'listView';

  $scope.setCurrentGame = function(game) {
    $scope.currentGame = game;
  };

  $scope.createGame = function() {
    if ($scope.format == 'Match Play') {
      $scope.skinAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
      $scope.birdieAmount = 'DOES NOT APPLY';
    }
    $scope.games.$add({
      name: $scope.gameName,
      host: $scope.user.name,
      date: $scope.gameDate,
      location: {
        course: $scope.courseName,
        address: $scope.courseAddress
      },
      rules: {
        amount: $scope.gameAmount,
        perSkin: $scope.skinAmount,
        perBirdie: $scope.birdieAmount,
        format: $scope.format,
        holes : $scope.holes,
        time: $scope.time
      }
    })
    $state.go('games');
  };

  $scope.check = function(game) {
    console.log(game.players)
  };

  $scope.addPlayer = function(game) {
    console.log(game.$id);
    var ref = fire.child('players').child(game.$id);
    ref.push({
      id : $scope.user.id,
      name : $scope.user.name,
      email : $scope.user.email
    })
  };

  // swap DOM structure in games state
  $scope.changeView = function(view){
    $scope.view = view;
  }

}]);

games.controller('app.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', 'Fire', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth, fire) {
  $scope.user = {
    email : '',
    password : ''
  };

  $scope.signUp = function() {
    auth.$createUser($scope.user)
    .then(function(userData) {
      // After successful signup save a user record to users under their auth ID
      fire.child('users').child(userData.uid).set({
        name : $scope.user.name,
        email : $scope.user.email,
        joined : Date.now()
      });
      $state.go('games');
      console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.login = function() {
    auth.$authWithPassword($scope.user).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.logout = function() {
    auth.$unauth();
    window.location = '/';
  };

  auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      $scope.activeUser = authData;

      // After user logs in find user record by auth id
      fire.child('users').child(authData.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        // Checks if user exsists
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          // sets scope user to the user data
          $scope.user = snapshot.val();
          // sets scope user id to the auth id
          $scope.user.id = snapshot.key();
        }
      });
      console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
      $state.go('games');
    } else {
      $scope.activeUser = false;
      // $scope.user = '';
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: What does the URL look like before and after you hit *reload*? At a guess, I'd say you're using HTML5 mode in the `$locationProvider` without [configuring server-side URL rewriting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

Comment: Where do you define the login logic? I do not see a login controller for the login page?

Comment: I added more code, hopefully this helps.

Comment: For instance if I'm here: http://localhost:3010/#/createGame and refresh I'm taken back to here: http://localhost:3010/#/games.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a controller for **games** state.

Be sure to include the $route service into your scope and do this:

```
$route.reload();
```